# Regular Expressions: how to accept any symbol

Tags: regex

I want to replace any content in my text file in between symbols < and >

What's the regular expression to accept any symbol ? I've currently:

```
fields[i] = fields[i].replaceAll("\\<[a-z0-9_-]*\\>", "");
```

But it works only for letters and numbers, if there is a symbol in between < and >, the string is not replaced.

thanks

Comment: As a suggestion, when you make Regex and you don't need to escape characters, do this: @"\<[a-z0-9_-]*\>" . @ disables escape expansion.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To accept **any** symbol, `.*` should do the trick.

E.g.: `fields[i] = fields[i].replaceAll("\\<.*\\>", "");`

Comment: You have make it non-greedy so it will be .*?

Comment: Xanatos solution is better :)

Comment: Mine is a little better only because the "terminator" is long 1 char. If the terminator had been (for example) "/>" (without quotes), then his solution (using the .*?, so the non-greedy) would have been better.

Comment: It's incorrect because `.` doesn't include `\n` (line break)

Answer (score 26):

Try this `[^\>]*` (any character that isn't `>`)

Answer (score 5):

Any char in regexp is "."
the "*" - is quantifier, how many. Thus if you want just one char, then use "." (dot) and that's it.

Answer (score 4):

**This is generic for the *bigger-picture* approach**, say you wanted to clean out (or select) any symbols from a string.

A *cleaner* approach will be to select anything that is not alphanumeric, which by elimination must be a symbol, simply by using `/\W/`, see [1]. The regex will be

```js
let re = /\W/g

// for example, given a string and you would like to
// clean out any non-alphanumerics
// remember this will include the spaces

let s = "he$$llo# worl??d!"

s = s.replace(re, '') // "helloworld"
```

However, if you need to exclude all non-alphanumerics except a few, say "space" from our previous example. You can use the `[^ ...]` (hat) pattern.

```js
let re = /[^ \w]/g    // match everything else except space and \w (alphanumeric)

let s = "he$$llo# worl??d!"

s = s.replace(re, '')  // "hello world"
```

**References:**

<sup>[1]</sup> https://regexone.com/